# WordPress main menu to toggle on click

Tags: wordpress, menu, toggle

Can't get my wordpress main-menu to toggle submenu 
Don't want my submenu to show on default

Found this but it's not working for me

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
$('#navmenu ul.sub-menu').hide();
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t understand jquery and wp, then find the function called `wp_nav_menu` in your template (most likely in the header.php), and add 'menu_id' argument

```
wp_nav_menu([ 
    'menu_id' => 'navmenu',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what I found in my header.php   But I don't know what to do.

```
            <ul class="main-menu desktop">

                <?php

                if ( has_nav_menu( 'main-menu' ) ) {

                    $main_menu_args = array(
                        'container'         => '',
                        'items_wrap'        => '%3$s',
                        'theme_location'    => 'main-menu',
                    );

                    wp_nav_menu( $main_menu_args );

                } else {

                    $fallback_args = array(
                        'container' => '',
                        'title_li'  => '',
                    );

                    wp_list_pages( $fallback_args );
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
```